# How to handle out-of-memory error in Racket?

Tags: memory, error-handling, racket

In Racket, is there a way to safely catch and handle out-of-memory errors without terminating the program?

Comment: First find out the root cause for the out of memory error, it's quite likely that you have an infinite recursive loop somewhere.

Comment: That's not helpful for my question. I'm not trying to find the root cause of an out-of-memory error. 

I want to be able to catch and handle out-of-memory errors. This can be done in other languages, such as Java and Python. How do I do it in Racket?